# Chrome not recognizing javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a standard page with a .jsp header included. In that header I have javascript code defined.

The page is rendered fine. Let's say I have `<a href=javascript:doSomething()/>`.

For some reason this works on IE and I can redirect on another page (which is the purpose of the function), but not in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Code I want to call:

```
function doSomething(){
    postUrl(path, { userId: client });  
}
```

My guess is that Chrome doesn't like whatsoever variables declared in the javascript code.

Comment: Have you checked that the function you are using is supported by that version of chrome? Post the code please

Comment: Are there errors in the developer console?

Comment: Hello, the only error I see in developer console is "doSomething is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,it may help you and also use debugger on browser to test

```
function doSomething(){
    postUrl(path,callMe());  
}

function callMe(){
userId: client;
}
```